# What would be the proper English translation of »Drops« in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

The two below paragraphs come from the *taz.de* article “[Frankreich im Wahlkampf. Es ist das Ende einer Epoche.](http://taz.de/Frankreich-im-Wahlkampf/!5399079/)” (My question refers to the next-to-last sentence of the second paragraph.)

> Dann ist alles durcheinander geraten. Im Sommer 2016 wurde Sarkozys
>   Kandidatur von unzähligen Gerichtsprozessen erschüttert. Alain Juppé,
>   der ehemalige Premier, war zwar gealtert, versprach aber Stabilität;
>   in den Umfragen verdrängte er Sarkozy.
>
> Aber ach, es waren ja nur Umfragen. Erst waren noch die Vorwahlen zu
>   gewinnen, um Kandidat der Konservativen zu werden. Mehr als vier
>   Millionen Menschen, die darauf brannten, es der Linken heimzuzahlen.
>   Dann, auf der Zielgeraden kam François Fillon, **ein konservativer
>   Drops**, aus seiner Außenseiterrolle zurück und ließ seine Rivalen
>   hinter sich. Sie waren sich ihrer Sache zu sicher gewesen.

What would be the appropriate English translation of the German noun *Drops* above? According to the [Reverso Dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/Drops),

> der/das Drops = fruit drop

Is the author really saying that François Fillon is a *conservative fruit drop*?

Comment: Vielleicht ist auch Droopy gemeint? Der heißt auf Deutsch in einer der Synchro-Versionen "Drops": https://bilder.wunschliste.de/sendung/hr/v0853.png

Answer (score 3):

Als Bedeutung von »konservativer Drops« könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass Fillon zwar harte Positionen vertritt, jedoch imstande ist, sich als gut verdaulich zu verkaufen. Er wirkt auf die Wähler sozusagen wie eine Süßigkeit. Ein verwandter Ausdruck wäre »Wolf im Schafspelz«.

[Wikipedia vom 23.04.2017:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Fillon#Ab_2016:_Kandidatur_bei_der_Pr.C3.A4sidentschaftswahl)

> Fillon steht für einen katholisch-konservativen
> gesellschaftspolitischen und einen liberalen wirtschaftspolitischen
> Kurs. Die Wettbewerbsfähigkeit der französischen Wirtschaft soll unter
> anderem durch die Abschaffung der 35-Stunden-Woche und die Schwächung
> der Gewerkschaften verbessert werden. Er will auch die staatliche
> Krankheitsversorgung erheblich einschränken. Der Staatshaushalt soll
> um 100 Milliarden Euro reduziert und 500.000 Stellen im öffentlichen
> Dienst sollen gestrichen werden.

---

In meinem Duden aus dem Jahr 2000 habe ich inzwischen noch eine andere Möglichkeit entdeckt (vermutlich der bessere Tipp). Unter »Drops« wird dort aufgeführt:

> jmd., der durch sein Wesen, Benehmen auffällt
> *(someone who stands out by their nature, behaviour)*

So einen könnte man »[komischer] Kauz« nennen *(oddball)*.

[image: Duden - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache: Drops]

Im Fremdwörter-Duden steht das vielleicht auch.

Answer (score 2):

I am actually not completely sure either what this phrase is supposed to mean. I can only offer two stabs into the dark:

There is a colloquial idiom saying

> ... der Drops ist gelutscht.

meaning "everything is done and dusted.", "the matter is finally settled and cast in concrete", also sometimes implying it was not the most optimal outcome. This would be the "standard" context the word "Drops" is used in German (at least in cases where you don't relate to the real thing).

How that pertains to the context, however, is not fully clear to me. It might be it relates to the fact they *finally* had a candidate, even though he was a complete underdog, and so maybe not the best possible choice  - but, alea iacta est.

On the other hand, it might easily be the sentence doesn't even relate to that idiom.

The sentence might also relate to the not completely sweet nature of *Drops*
always having a sour end to swallow - This would fit to the predominately socialistic orientation of the French voters having to swallow a sour conservative candidate for the sweet revenge with the leftists that sentence is talking about.

I'd rather have chosen

> eine bittere Pille schlucken

to transport this intent, though.

Maybe the author was fascinated by a mix of both and thought this was a good metaphor - And in the end failed to explain himself.

I have no clear and obvious explanation to that sentence, but I doubt anyone else has. This is maybe not the best example of illustrative wording.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard expression to describe someone in German, so there's no immediate translation that comes to mind. However, we can approximate one by analysing the register and connotations of this expression:

- It denotes someone who is **insignificant and without (political) importance**, as the size of the object of comparison indicates. This is supported by the context of the sentence: *[...] kam François Fillon, ein konservativer Drops, **aus seiner Außenseiterrolle** zurück [...]*
- It is used **without any further metaphorical meaning** (as suggested by Pollitzer's answer) **apart from its size**. None of these potential additional meanings of *Drops* are activated by the surrounding context; only size is.
- Its use is **derogatory**, as any comparison of a human being with a small everday object. (E.g. *Er ist ein dünner Spargel = He's a wimp.*)
- However, it is **not offensive, insulting or even vulgar**. It is something a journalist could say about a politician without sounding disrespectful. Hence, *mook* for example wouldn't work, as it is too strong.

Given all of the above, I would suggest *political dwarf* as a translation, which conveys most, if not all the meaning of the German expression: *dwarf* carries the meaning {small}, while *political* makes clear that this is not meant in a physical way {body size}, but rather refers to his {miniscule impact or significance} in politics. It is mildly {derogatory} while at the same time clarifying that this is not the opinion of the journalist, but rather refers to Fillon's rank in the political hierarchy / public opinion.

Comment: Ich glaube micht, dass die von dir angegebenen Gründe ausgerechnet "Drops" als relativ selten verwendeten deutschen Ausdruck rechtfertigen. Wenn's nur um die Größe bzw. das politische Gewicht ginge, wäre "Krümel" oder "Zwerg" bzw. sogar "politisches Leichtgewicht" wesentlich naheliegender. Irgendwas darüberhinaus muss der Schreiber sich bei "Drops" schon gedacht haben.